# Vim visual mode backspace deletes instead of moving cursor

Tags: vim

When I was using vim 7.3 in visual mode, backspace would move the cursor backwards.

I recently upgraded to vim 7.4 and now notice that now in visual mode, backspace actually deletes everything that's been selected.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can remap backspace to `<Nop>` for doing no operation or remap it to `<h>` for moving towards left.

Comment: Deleting isn't the default behaviour (try with `vim -u NONE -N `). Check your .vimrc and find suspicious lines.

Comment: Especially check your `:set selectmode?`  (Cf. `:h Select` and `:h v_<BS>`)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using vim 7.4 on OS X (Homebrew's version).

I solved the issue by adding `:vnoremap <BS> ^H` to my .vimrc file. (To add the `^H` symbol from vim when in insert mode use `CTRL+V CTRL+H`.)

You can find more information about problems with backspace
[here (vim wikia)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems).

Comment: i am using ideavim in Android Studio , and `CTRL + V` works